# Maildir and mailutils?

Tags: email, mail-command, maildir

I want to use the `mailutils` app on a install of Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS with a Maildir format, but every time I run the `mail` command, the system looks in `/var/mail/user`, instead of the `Maildir` directory in the home folder.

I'm aware that setting the `MAIL` variable will resolve this, however the changes only last until the user logs out. How can I make this permanent?

In addition, how do I configure `mail` to not save messages into the `mbox` file in the user's home folder, but rather keep everything in `Maildir`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Fixing the variable

If you'd like to make this change system wide I'd be inclined to add an entry in the directory `/etc/profile.d` for it. You can simply put a file in there with the contents as follows:

```
# /etc/profile.d/mailenv.sh
MAIL=$HOME/Maildir
```

or

```
MAILDIR=$HOME/Maildir
```

This environment variable, `$HOME`, should be in scope when the user logs in. We're putting this entry in `/etc/profile.d` so that it gets sourced when a user logs in, into their shell's environment. From then on, any subsequent "interactive" shells they may spawn will inherit the environment variable from the original parent shell.

#### mu-tool

You can also install the `mailutils` package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mailutils
```

Which includes the tool `mu-tool`. The following command will show your mail setup.

```
$ mu-tool info
VERSION=2.99.97
SYSCONFDIR=/etc
MAILSPOOLDIR=/var/mail/
SCHEME=mbox
LOG_FACILITY=mail
IPV6
USE_LIBPAM
HAVE_LIBLTDL
WITH_GDBM
WITH_GNUTLS
WITH_GSASL
WITH_GSSAPI
WITH_GUILE
WITH_PYTHON
....
```

#### Consolidating mbox

I don't think you want to do this. When dealing with mail there are usually 2 locations that you need to have. The first is often referred to as the spool or "post office". This is a location where the mail server can deliver mail. The other is your mailbox (aka. `mbox`).

The `mail` man page hints at this too:

```
 /var/mail/*                  post office (unless overridden by the MAIL
                              environment variable)
 ~/mbox                       user’s old mail
```

When the same server is tasked with spooling the mail, and allowing the user to read the mail, then these 2 directories will reside on the same box, in different locations. When reading the mail using something like POP or IMAP the "post office" will reside on that server and your mailbox will reside locally on whatever client you happen to be using.

#### References

- [Send and receive mails from command line](http://www.binarytides.com/linux-mail-command-examples/)

Comment: @NoelForte - NP, thanks for the Q. Good luck with your continued setup!

Comment: Oh, one more thing. Would you suggest using Maildir as the "post office"? Mail gets stored in `/home/user/Maildir` obviously, but I'm planning on using Roundcube webmail, so I don't know whether one way is better than another. Really new at this stuff– feel like I'm in the dark.

Comment: Additionally, the terminal says that `mu-tool` isn't a valid command, even after installing `mailutils`.

Comment: @NoelForte - I always leave the "post office" under `/var/spool/mail/$USER` on my systems. But I run a centralized Sendmail server setup, w/ IMAP (Dovecot) and Roundcube.

Comment: @NoelForte - I'm on 12.10 Ubuntu and `mu-tool` is part of `mailutils`. Try a `apt-cache search mu-tool`.

Comment: Returns:
`libutouch-evemu1 - KernelInput Event Device Emulation Library
utouch-evemu-tools - Kernel Device Emulation Library - test tools
libevemu1 - KernelInput Event Device Emulation Library
evemu-tools - Kernel Device Emulation Library - test tools`

Comment: @NoelForte - I'm not sure what's up, I don't have any 12.04 systems around anymore. You could also try `apt-file search mu-tool` to see if that file shows up in other packages. That might shed some additional light on the situation. `mu-tool` shows up in `mailutils` in 12.10 and 13.04.

Comment: Thanks for the info on setting up the `MAIL` system-wide environment setup. I'm wondering though why it always defaults to MAIL=/var/mail/$HOME. Where is the config setting for that in the OS? Shouldn't we be adjusting _that_ setting instead? (I'm on Ubuntu 14.04).