# How to receive new email?

Tags: email, mail-command

```
mail -f  /home/debian9/Maildir
```

When new email coming,how to receive it in mailutils interface?
There are 1 email in my /home/debian9/Maildir.
[image]

Sent an email from admin to debian9 with command:

```
echo "This is the message body of new emial" | mail -s "This is the new subject " debian9
```

The new email can't be displayed .

[image]

```
? list
alias alternates Copy cd chdir copy decode delete discard dp dt echo edit else 
endif envelope exit Followup file folder folders followup from group headers 
help hold if ignore incorporate list mail mbox next nos nounfold Print pipe 
preserve previous print quit Reply Respond reply respond retain Save save 
sendheader set setq sen setenv shell size source struct summary Type tag top 
touch type unalias undelete unfold unset untag variable version visual 
warranty Write write xit z ? ! = # * + | -
```

Which command can receive new email?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110196/maildir-and-mailutils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a specific command to receive mail, mail is automatically delivered and stored on the machine's filesystem (usually on `/var/spool/mail/username`) by the appropriate Mail Delivery Agent.

Mailutils is a Mail User Agent. To read received mail, use one of these commands:

```
mail -p
mail --print
mail --read
```

Source: [Mailutils documentation](https://mailutils.org/manual/html_section/mail.html)

Comment: Miss my meaning.

Answer (score -2):

I use

```
cd /var/spool/mail
vi <username>
```

this will open your inbox in the text editor vim